# When Getting Company Activity that are above 10,000

Tags: clio-api

When Getting Company Activity that are above 10,000

we are getting the following error

"An invalid argument was supplied: page_token is now out of bounds and cannot be used. To get a complete set of data use the bulk index"

we successful get till 10,200 records after this the first page callback we get the error

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

[Per the API Manual](https://app.clio.com/api/v4/documentation#section/Paging)

By default, requests use Limited Offset Pagination which is limited to 10,000 records that can be paged through.  To overcome this limitation, you can use the offset parameter to get the next 10,00 records or you can you use Unlimited Cursor Pagination.  It also allows you to get more than 10,000 records at a time.

**Limited Offset Pagination**

```
GET /api/v4/activities?fields=id,quantity,price,total&offset=10000
```

**Unlimited Curson Pagination**
To use Unlimited Cursor Pagination you must include the order parameter with a value of id(asc) and no offset parameter. For example:

```
GET /api/v4/activities?fields=id,quantity,price,total&order=id(asc)
```